# Is it correct and natural to say "leave off on something" meaning to stop discussing something at a particular point?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, phrase-choice

Could you tell me if it's correct and natural to say *leave off on something* meaning to stop discussing something at a particular point? For example:

> In the last class we **left off on** what saturated fats are, so let's start off from there.

If that's not natural, what would you say? If it is, then what are other alternatives?

Comment: See [pick up where we left off](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pick+up+where+we+left+off)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase *left off on* is understandable. You could also use the preposition *at* -
*we left off at*.

[Merriam-Webster *leave off*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leave%20off)
stop, cease
*picked up where he had left off*

You could also just say *We stopped at/on...*.